# Is it safe to use Nipe with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: configuration, anonymity, security, ip-address-leak, proxy-leaks

I'm not a Perl coder and hoped Tor users (more familiar with proper tor application and usage) could weigh in on the implementation and overall usage of such a tool.

Would anyone recommend against using Nipe?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about this https://github.com/GouveaHeitor/nipe ...

Transparently proxying all your traffic over Tor is essentially always worse than using Tor Browser.

Just use Tor Browser.

Answer (score 0):

The Nioe is a tool that has been in the community for more than 3 years, and nobody has ever reported any problems in security deployments ... So it seems very security!